# Creating customizable/overridable localizable.strings file in swift-based ios framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a framework in swift and there is a `localizable.strings` file which it uses. Is there any way that a user who is using my framework in their app can override this localizable.strings with their own `localizable.strings` file? What I am looking for is something similar to `Strings.xml` in android which is overridden by the `Strings.xml` file in the app which uses the particular `SDK`.

Comment: Make sure you are ready to tell user about the keys been used by you to fetch the particular string from your string file

Comment: You can decide on which file (your own or another one) fetch the translation. It's the `table` param of `localizedStringForKey:value:table:`. Setting default your table for instance.